# Cannot find any information on property [bankOffer] in a bean of type [game.Game]

Tags: java, html, jsp, javabeans

Currently getting an error that the bankOffer property in my bean cannot be found..

It is from my game.jsp file shown below:

```
<%@page import="game.Briefcase"%>
<jsp:useBean id="game" class="game.Game" scope="session" />
<%
    // If the 'open' parameter is received, it is converted to
    // an integer and passed to the method setOpen. The value given
    // is the corresponding index for the ArrayList Object.
    if (request.getParameter("open") != null) {
        game.caseOpen(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("open")));
    }
    // If the 'restart' parameter is given, then the restart method
    // is invoked on the game bean.
    if (request.getParameter("restart") != null) {
        game.newgame();
    }
    // If the deal parameter is given, then it converts it to a Boolean
    // value and performs a conditional test. If the parameter is true,
    // then the deal has been made so the page is forwarded to the deal.jsp.
    // Otherwise, the gameRound() is incremented cause it is NO DEAL!.
    if (request.getParameter("deal") != null) {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("deal"))) {
            game.setDeal(true);
        } else {
            game.nextround();
        }
    }
    // If there is a Bank Offer, it will display the amount offered with
    // two buttons to either accept or refuse.
    if (!game.getDeal()) {
        if (game.offerTime()) {%>
                <div id="bank_offer">
                    <div id="bank_offer_title"></div>
                    <div id="deal_button" onclick="deal(true)"></div>
                    <div id="bank_offer_text">
                        <div id="bank_offer_amount">$<jsp:getProperty name="game" property="bankOffer" /></div>
                        <div id="bank_offer_message">Highest amount left: $<jsp:getProperty name="game" property="highestAmount" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nodeal_button" onclick="deal(false)"></div>
                </div>
        <%
        // Otherwise, the Briefcases will be displayed along with a game message 
        // above the cases.
        } else {
        %>
                <div id="game_message">
                    <div id="game_round">
                        <% if (game.getRound() > 0) { %>
                        Round: <jsp:getProperty name="game" property="round" />
                        <% } %>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div id="game_text">
                        <jsp:getProperty name="game" property="message" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="cases">
        <%
                int index = 0;
                // Iterates For Each Briefcase 
                for (Briefcase briefcase : game.getcases()) {
                    // If the Briefcase is not opened, then it is displayed as closed with the
                    // number assigned. Otherwise, if the Briefcase is opened then it is displayed
                    // as open with the amount value inside.
                    if (!briefcase.isOpened()) {
                        // If the Briefcase is the chosen case, then it will be displayed with
                        // 'Your Briefcase' on the image. The Briefcase's once pressed invokes
                        // a JavaScript function called openBriefcase() which passes the 
                        // index. The function then invokes an Ajax call to the same .jsp which the
                        // html is then placed into the game container on the main index.jsp.
                    %>
                        <div onclick="openBriefcase(<%=index%>)" class="<%=(((game.getChosen() != null) 
                                && game.getChosen().equals(briefcase)) ? "briefcase_chosen" : "briefcase_closed")%>">
                        <div class="briefcase_number"><%=briefcase.getNumber()%></div></div>
                    <%} else {
                      // Once the case is opened it gets displayed with an open background
                      // with the case amount centered.
                      %>
                        <div class="briefcase_open">
                            <div class="briefcase_amount">$<%=briefcase.getValue()%></div>
                        </div>
                    <%}
                    index++;
                }%>
                </div>
        <%
        }
    } else { %>
    <div id="deal_message">
        Deal $<jsp:getProperty name="game" property="bankOffer" />
    </div>
 <%
    }
    %>
```

Hmu to link any other files required. The previous file is index jsp, that loads fine with my other dynamic content, but it isnt loading game.jsp.

Help would be greatly appreciated, this is the first time I've had to use jsp in any extensive way so I'm at a loss right now..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class `game.Game` has a bean property (not just a field) named `bankOffer`. A java bean property is defined by its getters and setters, so for `bankOffer` to be a property, the class `game.Game` must include the public methods `getBankOffer` (or `isBankOffer` if a boolean property) and `setBankOffer`.